# update mysql column with bash

Tags: mysql, sql, bash, shell

This is the code I got so far:

```
i=1
inputfile="data.txt"
    cat $inputfile | while read the_data; do
        while [ $i -le 100 ]; do
            echo "UPDATE table SET row=\"$the_data\" WHERE ID=$i;"
            i=$(( $i+1 ))
        done
    done | mysql -u root -pMY_PASS db_name;
```

This code partially works, but the problem is that the first line in data.txt is inserted into each row instead of new data lines into the right one.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Duh, fixed it:

```
i=1
inputfile="data.txt"
    cat $inputfile | while read the_data; do
            echo "UPDATE table SET row=\"$the_data\" WHERE ID=$i;"
            i=$(( $i+1 ))
    done | mysql -u root -pMY_PASS db_name;
```

:-)